# How to pull part of a NVARCHAR field based on certain text?

Tags: sql-server-2008

Im sorry for the terrible title, I can't think of a better way to state it...

Essentially, i have a NVARCHAR field that is filled with various production comments that look like this:
(1/22/2015 (blujo) - WO113315 In Process)

I want to pull just the 'WO113315' part out of that field. These are work order numbers, and will obviously be different in each row of the table. So for any field that contains WO% somewhere in it, i want to pull that WO% plus the next 6 characters after it. I don't think trim will work b/c the WO% number could be anywhere in the field. But it will always start with WO%.

Comment: And is there no possibility that the characters `WO` will appear anywhere else in that string (say, as a username, or whatever `blujo` is an example of)?

Comment: i guess there is always the possibility, blujo is the user name associated with the comment. right now though, only this one person does it so WO shouldn't appear anywhere else in the comment field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a combination of SUBSTRING and CHARINDEX.

```
DECLARE @VAL AS NVARCHAR(100) = '1/22/2015 (blujo) - WO113315 In Process'
SELECT SUBSTRING(@VAL, CHARINDEX('WO', @VAL), 8)
```

If you know that the work order number will always show up after the dash, you can also use the following to ensure you are starting the search at this point.

```
DECLARE @VAL AS NVARCHAR(100) = '1/22/2015 (WOblujo) - WWO113315 In Process'
SELECT SUBSTRING(@VAL, CHARINDEX('WO', @VAL, CHARINDEX('-',@VAL)), 8)
```

EDIT: If you're not guaranteed of a WO code, then the following case statement can pick it up. At this point, I would suggest saving these results onto a new field on the table (or maybe a persisted computed column) so that your server doesn't need to go through this each time.

```
DECLARE @VAL AS NVARCHAR(100) = '1/22/2015 (blujo) - RW13315 In Process'
SELECT CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('WO', @VAL, CHARINDEX('-',@VAL)) > 0 THEN
    SUBSTRING(@VAL, CHARINDEX('WO', @VAL, CHARINDEX('-',@VAL)), 8)
WHEN CHARINDEX('RW', @VAL, CHARINDEX('-',@VAL)) > 0 THEN
    SUBSTRING(@VAL, CHARINDEX('RW', @VAL, CHARINDEX('-',@VAL)), 8)
ELSE NULL END
```

Comment: this is eventually going to be used in a sub-query, can i simply replace @val with the field name?

Comment: Yes, I just did it that way so that it would work on its own. You could also alter it slightly to use it in a function (but remember not to use the function in a where clause, performance will be poor).

Comment: one last thing... can CHARINDEX be used with LIKE? after speaking with my planning supervisor, it is possible that there could be a work order that starts with RW instead of WO. Or should i just create a second subquery to capture the RW variant?